# Large Java Code base Analysis using ant or Sonar Runner giving heap size issue

Tags: sonarqube

While analyzing a Java code-base with multiple modules and total code-base of 22430 files (total 189 MB, only java source folders) using Sonar 3.7.4 and Sonar Runner 2.4 and the sonar runner failed showing out of memory. The "Sonar Runner" was running on windows machine with 4GB RAM. Tried to increase the heap size to 2 GB but machine allowed only 1 GB and the runner failed citing out of memory. Also tried by disabling 'findbugs' from profile, then also it was failing for such a large code-base. Tried putting up individual modules as separate project and found that modules which are having 30-40 source files (less than 500 KB in size) are successfully analysed, whereas larger ones are failing.

Therefore have the following questions

1. Is there any recommendation on system infrastructure for large code-base analysis? For example 10 MB codebase must have at least 3 GB memory heap etc.
2. How can we run the entire project with multiple modules for such large codebase at one go instead of dividing it into module wise projects?
3. Also is it possible to narrow the scope of the analysis by pointing the runner to analyse a particular package inside one of the modules? I saw option of selecting modules only to narrow the scope.

Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not aware of such recommandations (for example 10MB codebase requires 3 GB of RAM) but the only thing that I can say is that if you provide enough RAM, you'll succeed.